# Meteor Mongo Collection is not using typescript interface

Tags: mongodb, typescript, meteor, collections, interface

I want to describe Mongo.Collection schema via typescript interface to have a strict check for type on fetch, forEach, etc.

```
interface IChat {
  _id: string;
  name?: string
};

const Chats = new Mongo.Collection<IChat>('chat');

// (method) Mongo.Cursor<IChat>.forEach(callback: <T>(doc: T, index: number, cursor: Mongo.Cursor<T>) => void, thisArg?: any): void
Chats.find().forEach(c => {
  console.log(c._id); // Property '_id' does not exist on type 'T'.
  // Why "type T" if it should be the type IChat???
});
```

But facing next error: `Property '_id' does not exist on type 'T'.`

What I'm doing wrong?

[Link to typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHEFMDtIJwIYBdIBNQCMCeolYA4CW0A5gM4CwAUCKAMoD2ArnAMaQBcoAFkkvmQ4hEAdwB0JQkm5MMTMvFYNoKFWKUBbYBsgoGcALR4ipMtt2R9wAJyRrANgBmABgAcr1JEj37AdmsAjM4IACzWAEyQAKzWCADMIc6o9nEBrHFxzlEYkM7AAWJxwNyQCJ5wYqhiSJRU1NS0ULCIKOjYuATE5A1gjCzsXLz8gsII4pLSsvKKyqpI6gxaOnqGxl1my5ZwNnZObh5ePv5BoRHRsQlJKWkZWTl5BUUaCMSV1bXEKHCOCOygAKoAJQAMnRQABvaigUBwSAKJAABQQZDIIn0qC4AAokAwANYwLhkJBwLoASlAAF4AHygIkk0gAbihoAAbvBCI4sABRZ6EAA2WJx%20OghOJZMpNLpXSZVGhMDgDD5fIAgqwlEwVIK8QTaWLSOTqbr6SQZQBfepUTysPkIWGgDQMVBMPmQUCq9UqMgQ5ks22gFh8wQAkF0GXMxwa1hIQjKf0KOCY0lcACyFn0Yn%208bDstAEegUZj0Dj8AAkqhE6LjdnoXmC7HWLDkJBM-BMQx8NHlEHITnodM4NAEDoAPyV6XMuW8vmjo3j3ugfDI1HomdSxkThcKxz8yAzgDyGAAVpAozLoaaADSgVgIJUYX64mcAMUjnegSdn67qOdrb%20vym3Eg2w7Qtuw3BRoFQAA1dltxvN8eReacuAwBhFVKaAz2hXN9AwQhUAAYT5QgYCQd1mBUAjGzfGdUPQhBMI3WEpSjKjSjfAAhbkpwAEUWF5oFXPUSFAAAfUAX3zN8sOhPkGEkaAuQADyIFpCxLaAeIQLAyBnaAmA0HI4Bk0AGAQJhpDoE9YSQABpSAsCEqtmVND8WQYfDq1zV9C1M6BgXk4hMVrLhJLrd8uB7bDdXbLEDRpdz8Jcrzf185QAoUp8kJYSBgsjUKfOUD8ouwolYtARMJVZDzUGSi0a0Kos5IUqy4BZQh2DIAiAMIEgcvLD86JdBiUsavykRISAArKDKgpCiTGrcmqzQtK0bTtB0nRdUAACJNisX4PRqAx7wUHbvRzT54B%20P4gVBC7ouY3QkRRNE4AxCqhR1NcSHiz8TQ3NkSU5RD%20S1YUx31KqfpM%20VFRVNUKKQcHvuEv6YZc%20r7UdZ1XXIjUage7DfTgf04EDLg7tDLGGqk3z%20wrUBUxWDMsxp7y6djfsy0ZjHv2i1L62o5t42At8wPnPt40HEdIYByXQEgKcnLnaLoUXV6Vzlkz1a3Hd9yPE8kBMy9r1vPl71YR8Cs5iL-q82nwv-aBALF0DIo3aEIOg2COuQQtQeQzA0OGxiFccXD8KIkiVHxyjqMLWiQ4wnWYThMVWIT5QuMDvjeUEuWxIW23U%20a4hlNU-3lA0rSdL0gyjNTsyLO4KyG10ezHO1jdXK4RLUAdjmnfSwLoDy-MbfC4rPZi-A4qq-ue8HwWixHzLsthcfWEnt9p4Vsq54qv7F-nU1l7GsvoFa9rOu6l3ev6xmhpT9mV-GhBJum1BZrH%20awt3vuy1MZUHNN%20NatpXSbVxm6RGBMvQlTfqwbgDFJovWXO9NsfJUBoLeh9H6V5YAiBweiOWV4bx3gfM%20RagDPJYzfhHOAJAGCIiXLgt2XYPbziVkhFWX5zxkPNpba2xcp40IHnQsaT0WGawwV9EU-0CGQCIawkhCizYUKtlQ22S1aH8yHn%20IGHJuJIWxNqeR%20D1EW0oTvQsOjxF6LfsoQOMFgZ%20zfMCYguJMTkKsVbGxRUxGjVtn5Lk0AFRKh0CoDx0AvE%20KEf4u2-cgnD2gICOEz0VHvWibEwRD4El2OSX%20ZqCkSAaSfsnEaEjgnNWYEgbxuTNH5MCVUp2NSLJ7mkPAaOpEyD1I0cI-%20tjml6JJv6QgnDopKHvkBds4sJlq1hAARyYOnBE8ANCEBRKBA2x5TwzyWSsoke5HCOGIrAAAKmYnZRtU4MPYMqfA%20AFS%20j5AiBUGgOzXL2QrDW6DUB0F6vpfAT4SJYN0t3U%20BS6ogNWiedakCcbbT2mmbYh0kZkBOsiSA50SpQO2nHQmJVHZ-iQSgyAxCMGKmwZkvBwlFHKJkbS40Aj%20laNEdVXRG56H6CYdIv57DoASzVorZWELoqmzidYkRACOX2K5ZI9JfK2FyNIaAQhFKmVdBZb4gZ1DZXn2CYYkGU5TEQzUZKxp0qhn6tfmNJxU4XEcjcYWbJfSdVNJtXo4laVFJhPhpEpArqLW4g9Uk21wTlBpPhBqoNDSQ1WoCZ6%20V1T5IlLKYNCpYdk2tPkrUt1Qi2UyrDV6-Rvk2lIA6SUOA3TPT5qlYMxNxbAZ%20iYOMomkyeozJAhw9tCzIDLNWeszZZBtlcAPLs42M9oQHPTsc05xBICXOFF8ydCsaz6HuY855t43mLE%20WOw23zhXqxpQCkgQKQWQDBbw%20Wwre6evFVhUBoDqBXW%20L8V0gdL1gqJo4d5M5KqGj5l7WQE6AP9hTCi1m8B0bCSwigJSSBwPxkgyzFscArwBjlrB5yOZeAaCDpiCDTMoPocw%20TbD0M4PUBfVQN9N1XQAAlSjlCJgAbXwnLAAuhC2j9GP2gEDucpW%20AbQoHgeGd5YraRSEgAAOSHJwe2zIShlHgOC0AzG1PGWZFIjVXAv2gtQGQLCcMlQEoM1Ob9xmsJGuMWDQTVmjMmZo7C60EDsZbTxrAz0RNRncP5MJj5Ym4SWaQkF0TTYXMOLGmUVAgciPxjLKqwhgdVVGpIqgJO9FElAJi8E2EDo2QJe5pq0gV4AsCn%20lC-LKS2JNnQ1vUNeXwxjW3JBdDOcTWVewweidhTfLtdQJ1rA6GZa5X7ON3roBx03JaX%20b2oTwl8gDSVpLZWSAVdFdV4ZrXgneyjRkxla3Swba2zw6bTafxjW9o6uCVdFImtK6qyrN6at7advCMbinEunZS0o77OhLsteu-to7-LntqPVTS1VszR29vLSup973QdOxefhJscmAeiz-nq5%20lTasGNvBjlAP9lR8BE3U3H2j5lexxIfQDCUarQuZPxv4JYoLE9QE2MnFOPlIAIhgPcHYJPzmMEp4D2FzYMBEGgFCmbYZwAVHAVDWwxBciV-oEyxHmZq-QyZKZsBwqq-THfI30kNzLG4I6BTQPlPzit46ZUjCDI9K4AxLAbGuNPtc2AuFHm8WumRSsYAaK4GYrOkTNnn6nNXuM72v9iwAM4dVqVUDRtkPwBNxUdDKe%20HYQQ0hrEOvSPxnI1Vn6efb3YXw4RkvaGy9kwr2jKjuHzxY2j5plj8Be0cY2zx%2037e9Gd6EyJkLouBZScH6VWTtuJfUfnKp8oGmtPlBMnpmHjmkLWei9FMzCMjphf5Dvkydm0tb%20P85n3ejA8wKOhP4mfpKsRfH0fvkL%20osGqdnFk7cBktQ6UXPwsQyzQGy1DhRwFgVSK0gF-3-wsR6x2yTXnEcWgHqxQEa2p3ZSu0gOCSGxGwSwQMrz6zmxLXoWIGG3jC4kBwm2lkU2m1m2%20WzQWxgHiz9QiVIlgLOxFQu0QOwOwjfgO0VQ1U4Je22yIKQJwM%20xYLu2dXtRMUh3gLELRl22QJu10GoN%20z-y4MIWoOB05VULByVXRE0LgLpTVSUX0zUThy7BnCJWwkR2IKPWwnvT4O9VjHR25xQCxxEAwPygTTtnxyzQMLRy5x51HnJxQH5ya38L3mFQPnnkNBPkfXZk7w51CNJ3CL5w7EF2F0JRnnF2k2iml1lw%20kCNTngGV2z3V01x0wVnrz1zZgVkNyNkLCqLNxaOUFTkd1QDn0KOwm6Odz6gDSDA9y9xNmAVo3AQ2kRVdA4htAAC9XQSpRkoISIRAuBVilE6AkB-ZWAvJO9NiRBtjdje1CFMRxsb0rxYRIJ4AG0C4YiNi1jr9WcVBroBNDjTi6Dp8T1rikBDjHilETJNk0C5dg4csgSyA0kbjYRSiFcNxNkeJ04FQsBQSyimIWCukkYuB9JDJ4ATJzIcQ4ANRMQiToAwpmtdFoplBDiQTyxMCi08sqToBDi0kygsBoi7iasmTDjES6QGAUS6S-DOThkBZCA4AiQ5NHRcoPxJTPATIbQJSpTGZZTIATJIjIsUAuAP8UA1Sx8mwNIiQGJ2BGZtTIADSdj8xVTgFoRRlWAWBfj-jQBDiBtYxNlTTMQXkVl3doAsAM1wSO9Xj30-hmM%20R8B1NkwEB8Be98QsBuMElnjLpAyGNBM2RPQIyoy7C2MYy4z-CEybS-RTStS9SUBjjow9iAyvhkzTTSyOpTilEPS1i59Li05oS7jC1rVTTB5YRJAiR4AQywyEwps1F6TrVi1opiBDTLSTTiyzTBULT2ADd7TSItIdjGYPcTJFxfiVyEBziDJgRIA2QKY1UG4YNvSsA8zQBO9TTe12olFejviWzyg7j4yNwpk6QmAoxDjGZnSNwl8izgsmwTIhtMQFAXQox9BptGNzlkxgQuQXQA0gLyDlQlQQKr0jYILECoKYK4KlZSIxiNwAASM8kyZQWk7xDACk%20xJkqE8oNAciyikizSJE-kui1gCih4h9bCduJsD6O49fDEmEl8%20cTwPkgUoS6KEoUM9TTESSgcsgdMrgfs8MyMrk7CA8npTEdStMyMgzVMmodM1S2jfM0mU080o0pTUyuc8yms8s4fJMgTSyyc9gGyuskQBspRAEkQD8Ry%20cq0nMIyy8%20yv4Hy8y3tAi1CsCwk6bdcjcAk-QYk0k8kjihg1daKTwhARw1K-g8giK9ClXTC6C2C%20C0iRCyCZCvkXK8C-K8QrCoq3ClQfC5AsUxUzwTK%20U5EJAFUtq8CWQMgBsQgHIc4r4ixMQUa20cgM8r3D8XXdMOgXq-q7taARjBiVAF0EyMgeakkRayEljdkv00OU-NY7q-y%20bXyLkX4bgTEcapKu4shWYUiG6xqCrQMSAMKdsxNH8wnXyf4aAF0FEbxZQVAKQQsR622O614lQUG8KZ6hQN6j1T6j7P8EsRwAGyCYG5QKGt8cGuYTGwsGG16yMd6u2BG1HP8fcupPCNG0wBJbGh6oUvVEmtwosAAdSkEuvSsyqLluudhxvpppydKeNOtjEmiQG3M0uKpUD3DgEOJnFqpwoDSLkOI-BSpdKLBFq-LQoDVlsKvltIg-EZtLVjEKwYDZBJIErQEdKVpUKZsfNbHVJCylsdOvPEkOKvE3NIi6tABVMUUQxVJnG9oXAgRUBls8v1sFq%20qNoEtZukDFvtqbEdqOtAGdoFqUSvA5pm0PSQC5qesDt%20M9oDtgF9qlP9qlLdqDr%20LWJnCtpTpEFVtwAYFquxBnITo8qTpnMVrWI-D5kRt8hxFquju4FjubulsTuTtdtAHTpSuzv5r5kmP92mK812n2m2AwAWOxSJlvzmIQEWJvL9EtrWJssHgOIPp2LLN7WhDOIuNVWuKfMaiJrDsBJ7hSKCtdA%20LsIvuGoX2FXduDsTs%20uFWBOFlhP9IVk2RovgFRLhNAbIF5OJBYuAYOv2QEu6gJmxJPNqOFTitJJJI1FxsbUZLVmpLWLIpHPwcpMIeZLWNZNQHZNIdy3Ie5LWNgeRLorodUtFPFM6qVJlKlNLg6pVOVN4fyJnP-I1L8uFTjpQDMqnO8pnOkYXKfvnFtKXN-tboNptrdJnI9NvC9NAA932pfhLU7yUvFPTPPtACzIchzL4sUfhJfpTJ6TMffosezP%20gHxsdPnZlGULLboApLNPo6iPvserICdYHMbONvJECbOvoErbI9U7PZmnUgB7K%20BMaGrtwsTYZFLVgnN8unL8dnKcvEbVjtKV2XOQB3I-Bip%20XLrFpxP3MPKDBxKMiqZ9PGKMeCfbuccifvMl0elicanEpKa7GJA-IrvrIftrpnj-N8bEduRytArysgp1olqytFLKpQsWaquWewtWcauFSIr0baZnlIqAfoo4rHIofAZhPOeFM4qZOYfgdub1UucmSAaGf6ehNBI8eFRErgbEtzOmavTkpkuBeUsPhMfkpUuyb3z0t6S0v0p0oce0vwHYdAACuMtmZC3kYsrkasstMPufsrIcrxaKZcucYib-s7tEexfxYUc8Y6eJeCtJd8vMfCq2aisQOqcwYsnirHkSr5vZRVpnknszvmcgkqs5ZqpWfqrWeyo2Yqo5Ywuld2dlf2bVm3E4c9uFYVgVK4daozv6xng2owD6pJEGqHJGrGsYRGJ9KmqqLmtNYWrfGWsgjWuNc2sIG2uob2vlxAeFUieOvFXDSdnOqQSusYTwegFpshsFaxsVherho4vUcNqLB%20r%20t6SmSBrfCjZjaQFzYTdhsJvhvDqYN8mRtRuzZBrjbxp5rponn8PxqTbuZTbfnJsxEpqBupsbbrdjYbZbdLeCL-AHsxFFYnWnuht7fzZrY%20sHckL-BFrFs1tIhbpEG1tVYVpdupcNZILLeFt0A1tWfXbqoDUma-z-GNtNpvogegipaUQgP4IVWhKboKdXZpabA7tTtzo9qlK4ALsgCLs8BLs8DLodMrtDs8vPd8mvbgAHqHtfZHtbrHrWLToqc5vEm5p-v1aU3-cA93D-dLu-dUbXYg5rqg9jD7sKpfbEbfaxY-a3fvYhT3aLEo5grg4qeo4dsQ-WLo5QE-ZEFQ52PQ44sl2fTc3hU82gQ4gVBEHjAREVA6hwGWL9D-SHC6Fpwns2WKMZlebThYiQEuSlt6iCn0GM-MWUPub0aVBl3Kp04IbPixltPus1F7WKK5BeTs4Yas7khEA0jOUgG2KwD%20s86oql2s989%20oXToGdd6TReKLoEUyM8yn0Fs7i-C%203P%20HJifBS5QrS586S%20IGy7gFs9M4Uj0NC%20hGKJLGeEmgK7HlK%20IHK-xPC9TCBoQDq7bBJDK94IIcq-C%20y8lq65M6G-M%20NDy5l0C5dA64a9G7JBhe84m%20dem5G6a9iv68QB0GW7M9W-nGKLvjmHOQIAC%20gA5HayAnG5EHKv25XZG5C%20a586u%20c9Foqcy4qou8e4hqQAS829u4fehCBrIGKNS-m4B6q8i9gEm7hDu43FB-C-c9vGh%20Eq0-C786i5i8R7SuR584G7qTRdh-y8zox%20wnx5s6VGu5UCJ4c5hT93cwXugWDy2GAAwBk-jAMHwAU9YCwAME0AdGgBxWZE3pZ-gHk%20Ik593tJlU42VIA0-%206x5lyJ-6f08M9u5m528wfC%20B8s6p%20bVJimTmBl4W5EHh7e-m76589R4h7wGC7RbN5lwt4C-R5t8N%20%208gDq6K81909t5EAy6y5y5N8s697d7986%202566869%20q4-ld5V5W7D4q7C589a8IHa5j9D-EM98N5x62%206-T964T4m6t%20j7M5D5z4s4z-i6W9T9L7G9N8z426L4UhL8a7j9Tj26e8O7DLoBO5OS6AV-z8u7J6e466d6B8H8%2059-9-L417H7mBd%20H%20trVhJ4H8n7z9l8B5R-B4C8L9i9r6X%20N777X7B-8%20i62pqAP80-X%20x9mHP6X5Spv7l%20X-J9x-m6p6Hzntp4RUXojKQCQT8z9GVB9LEUfQfobYsaCAE5hRkGkFAJNHyrctWQfoDiJmnAGYsNQngdrKCTgGjIUq4AnurGFyKFgEei4CnAODPIGMCcuAosClQ0jWgmAXbICEDSUCkC-WiDCOpQNgDHJMQo1MQEQK%20CCpJqXGVpueSFos0q0uULNujXkT6McBpNXuunG0Z8hdGHuMusQMkE%20kyBYcd-hJ0QQlArY8gxQT6WUG8CmBSBKYp-3p7L1gASCE8LiH545hb83-X-nYVGQADYyRzIQUoxAHCRkBj%20UmFAOSZZ43Bp%20BAUgMCE69-QNxdAR9DgGYtsBoQ0gmNHwHKBCByAIwW4PUHkdKBmdagQoLoGjsOoDAYwWiXiHBI9w7AlGlwJ4HwA%20Bbg%201nEOY6gBmaogythIOMHVN6h4mOpJ6SUxKDA6KgwoVAyHwUDrwOgrxF0LPKGCqhxg4tJoIDwzFQAPEHiAiEBA85CAGyL4FHnsYOCq0vacXDeiLiYhsQR3SjIaECKkgTIV9f6PsPSbz4xuVUU4drnWx7DxIBwhQi3hOGZozhr5ZQObnUhZZC4zw1Gj8OrgbY-o9w18sRFIjKhUAqAZiBph%20hXDrQMcMiNCNhHHCaQYIk6qwL0bQjAQuMTEM8B-5VoUwyAKwRhmPIaA0kA6IkE03QZXhowOgPwW1FvBoNcScALugviGGXtIAuIl0DgxdCmEa%20YJFgTMLp5IoLB0I-AAYBaCQADAxENYfAFsHQhb8CwpYSsPlGkw7CneLYT3mca7D-hFUQ4WGTRFCiMInwhWBcPhEAjLWbw9ER8NTilYnhBo14bcPeE5YzRwqZouFDLCOiDhnot8AKPFCujwCqcREZCJRFwg4RwkBERCNjjhiUQxojEcG2KHf4cReIgkaSOJGEj4ABCAyJSMOQ1AWRRkOkasNnJfAXkhY08vbnqFcieRuUIkvyJBHMDDGb-cTrMMXoqiNhTLV0CqPJY9UnW5rXKNaOZSgAuBzEZGDUIEEOtPWi1V1qtWKbQgfE%20I3QNbi4IVDbQimL4La09yTjLOkZUTOyW6Kqo1x9fTcfwLRbdFekJYGanAGZgriYGHUN8LaFcFSC4h0UQ0kgHkCMwexp9eQPxT9F98Ae-4tFpGhPDfCjYlPYQaAAAD65sR1may9biwfW5SEBsyHFz0AfxXoCkKAAADkfotANhKLi4SwJBYUgARPEjYSfgO4VAGRJwkiAXg0YUiYRIYAnJ-O2E-YvY2-HIB5AvaPCQg2bGlQMJXAUsr%20PRLEgsAKDFzs0zxKiS4AWAc5CWPrisj%20KyIZQDegvKIJiJdSLDIgU4llkVoNPCTsqMWHdQNAvPTsW8T%20C3jHQGkdyPBF8h2Ezi1haoeCHvRWTUANkhgHZM6LswNQq9TyV4j%2060h1C62Ewh9CklsjsmYnAyW2PMEopgAEoxUZJ22gdjNRHExYb2P3iesLWn9YcaOPThnipx-YhCYWFnHusmi5sJcdIEdBHjRqm5DcepgKkB89GjyPkAeOXHVS1Ex4%20qeKUakZ8LxmIK8Sijcn3jwoT41occ33gYSvx6UjCanFhBATd%20myBaU1JAnLTdOGLVNtBNgnTjEJu1ZCSwI3BoThJmEnCbxJolEToAPwxieRMokuhqJhEuicDWuk4TmJ86WAGxKJYWTuxM0riQ-g7SXSjYkDf1mrHfHyAhJs0pBmJIknjjwpc03QLJPkmyxyRjcJBipPuJ9N0WIbElJpKIwUYdJP0vScAgF5zCVRJksyalK7EkYqp7k6ALZIezhN6yTk7sK5Pak0y6ZFuEtH2GgB%20TdBgUr2MFNOyhSKxEUrXhMQtAj4AAUnQD3AKZV6kAAiPIBxAaAO%20SxZkNaGUDSkDMUsmWQgDlkKyyoyso7qZmWS3hekzCIkTuyjDpDUJDAbWXJk5wKDNZoAO2brLKnQhxcc%20XmAvlASSzpZss7aCVEsauCfoA%20cKUXEtEmiGIRcKeuJHCle5w5wkeOeJBSpJz5h9HAEJ8FcDO5EAOAcSFyBdl6zFZiwFWfpM7wFyA5zIIOTmTDniQI5gRaOZnSLhxyuMCc40KnJTne5fcvsmWYrEQwsEvQ%20cv2a7KWIiizB20QeT3IQSxZoRKs64aqhuiElXB8grgOXMgB-QJ5-s%20WUXMNlhkH2iCOSLAFAAAAeJOqABpDLyk63lOuv2iYCmyrqWsv2VeHYobyrwTM2whuBjJS1ygVkQVMDTZBgF%20J96IoUMMTwaA7ZDslZBfNXmCC66myDiMQCfGYglImVa2RAL9CEJ4Fg4WSdIJtqbkFAIFYkNNg3l10foRiC%20S-NMjbV3584cgqRAAVRzY56DVuangXEMRlAfsIOEUPPDsjcMQwnEOAp0a5RyxgmO2R%20FXn6TqApgpKUHgsGQBDwZAZQIlO7mbz9ZSslWTxIPlOyN5w81RcXKNkbgb5d882QEJSqoLoo-Cv2RAqdniLDpR3T2TwtTygJoQyi4edGSsZuNhZzC0gEXHrnJzG5jC1kanJ%20jtzM6qclcq6HEj-BM52c7SEXG0WFyDZJc60oFUpmry3Fwc4SKHKYW1yox4kXxZbKzoBKjIQSxOS3L8UTp1WTilJV9JEV%20ze5qgePPEoDkBVb8G8hPNPNQCzyhxWqXML8EXlYhhF0CqqE0q3mJKjugU-eRrOPmnzz5wi85FfKxm%20RDFgYe%20bUpllPyH56yyheLGoXCpP570eAD-JHTRh-5TYgnOKlQX1DQFAix2VAqHlyyYFiy10mQEwWILkFBSsxT4PMIiBXl2CuoUO18h4LcodIIhXbIyH-QyFwiihW-IN60KVA9CosEUp7w5K28JTNhSd3IQIqTYDir8O0NtmWLBF5C0RSvPuVuzMZ1PSRfPTHkx4kIv6NQhKyZkadQFakw6QwEdHBLO584NUOytKUmQMA3K-URyv4r7jLkPKtuZyrfHp4owLKsXAByLwPla8MqiSt3nFJI5YqfAC6sMRXTqslRSEEyez3jAzgIy-IfVQwEaLcLhkfGTYXqr3Rmr4AiQwVETDhA3hO%20yYc5AiDOVhw5Q%20YR0Op2nykpxSugaTPiEgD4AOIaoT1VhDuQwFcS0ItAJH0mhBgiho8%20AaTGNV8hTVKGJmDao%20R2q4AhLOjNapNW2r4wGUi%20ozO2rEji1ua%20MA6rIDTUc1Bq6SdTy1GNq81RMOLKvlbDdLys8Ax2WryClIBUwKIKPg6uChT4LEOIVVKhBoaqpa8A6ukKUA0DDrAek0InkQDDIELGwGgM8qAGAAAAqfdbmDIBiBmaJIfxtutACHqwANWFNbfgZ5WBKsiU1pVOHaVg4GVla8xsyr6Luy2Vgq3lTPAFWXCUVXQHVdhH5WsAxVoGiVX2hFV-rgN-0MDSBkzpKq1YheVDRJSQAEYMNNeFVRph1aYMNVSCLVZlSQ32g21hqqtRmpLXNqLlkUisjUvTWZr7V21XtM6sjIBc3VHqyOV6rUo%20q6BfRANfCD6Ihqw1EanjUBQ3Qxqcgca9yTV1CwSaiZaCtNRRoCFMaaN%20a0JlhFbXVqm1mmk4g5IrVzJs1umvNXWobWmbzV5K5xUWuo01qdRsVaEV2sHI5SelYwlvuBF0ArrR1i1cdYsFVRTq1EM6jJcOPnUeb5wi6ocN5rXVosN1wK4kEut3UHqj1jgE9WetkygCl1V6-dTevo0UrLQVK6RZpnOTurzJQZJjCVqWE3z04PEp7jhvSozhohoAAdLJJw11SNAGmZxn3hzI-Ql4sVFuDhqXzqZdlasbrR4v%20h9axcJY2pIpJRnIF4YMuNJEDXmk1AsVSmmzZTKgruqo07PQVKrIi0YTuoQHYWSZCG2qqDeY2kOXLEm3-S5g9Wipo1ommDCZB9YCqYeLUTaSLEMK4re6rEBbaqtVIpAFeGRBYB8wBEONPfUUqVa-tlWnbV2D8pDDPAFVT7WYR8R1rtav2-7XmPTjA6yAoO1gODtZQep-tMO7bXCF20KA66ItXGc3mHFo6qFUOzHbDuq1Ehcd%20OwnTqkh0-aEQpOqrWQAp0I6XtRYA1VpLxkWJ6dOyxnTzqx0s6gdejPHWDoh3E7odMu-nfDrrr4ALINO1VBLvhwk6ZdgOtnYrqJ0cV9dzOtXXtrrqLj3tFiFHcOO%2012E9edCvog1qDbYQWtXcB8u1vw1it%20t0gQbXhrVVTadAM2k7VygW0iAltYpI2Bpi4XYRoA%20ACkbLvR1u7oQOQBhAFxYJE0n0RugnUrtN0q7zdAuiRQVo-5FaH12wIYPgGfVzD-tvaYxszsB3mMnd8Kn9RPQe3eDooHunDT8SHCdap0FjTjONt60KxX%20asAktwB708BA9BvaEJdsyXXbR9qcekZYAsizbaNGrCPVHpW2x6BhzhT6eVu51w69t5jUGV1GLph6FYZ2-vWukH395F9d6EMXVrb2u7Xx%20%205MSSje2szVUdunpd9rN1k7Dd8u9nfnruYAG%20dxep5UWCR3a7zU5sFPdzt53Y7WdwB43ZzuV1M6ydFuynVAdADU7f9va3XTYSl1IHZduejnQWgwPS6i96u3AyLtgPi74DDOxAwbvzHkHQDeqcA8fpwMf7AVWugg5tksQIGuDZB1A3npN1gHC9WByA7wde0oUbdZhAQ6-OYPOMW98qjGf9w70FLU43etvd7qD08t-dbe6-QYbQ3Ta19l%204VBHHC7b6Y9a280YnuQMVpmDBGtWOnv0CZ7II2enuOwYkOcGpDEB2g5iLvVzDrxRMZLRADkj3g%20Qm4dsF6GvXADSYwJGMeOLj2jJgS6IE2hlUU3KbLyZAa%20AELSN%20hNku6J0MbhyOYtYQw0BQNJlGTwgGJE1XtJrtXodQLtQ%20q7W4J8Mbh59xoAfB7mhTQgIj4AKI7eFiMCBstwALGBEfQwTGXilM9DIHFc5xigwGMkAnxPOXWbqlh%20mY3YSgn4QcNk2RTDhsqwaYFjU4MDdxVaDk519GDbCE8mYn6xO9QUtqB1DhCPb3Bz2m2gzA-D65IJpWL2aitGT9ggwyYZQEwjEDdQlQHRIsCfJmM0gsI0x%20MLMb0QRGNcyuZE5izRMYUsT%20mwmYmUpk4my18e%20shUWVa5LkZ2YtOGjObKeAdi-ISMYKJxPX4NtNSnE2xpqL6jYZ6Jaky7t0BIQGTji5kKiZqLImhTh6qmSuIxObT%20pF4lBQv0QQVSe1ghrgeNS3G1C2hQu5qfuLnlqJVTmyzeV7mUOS7e0j0%20VXHuhAgSNqfIJAGknYCEA2QfwwFv5V8PoGOKcAiI25NFM5hpj5MKU2-F1kKKFB6BcmJiCIGT7YcKhzzaU3w4VHsIsISLOwACjkJrcRIew49DQhIBXuqG%209JLh9MxGEjKJ8U4jNX1Z0CzNteEIyI850M06V6bSMLI-BcmsR8IYs3mmrMT1azrg8KQ2fQZW7hof%20QMh5yH1dn5TY0a0KUDgAtmtdQ59BnvLGhoDWwWTTihEcnOlmctUx8UxZHpN%20mbsOxOAB%20PwAckXmIOG2iIEQD4BlQCu1gIebBp1tEMK6R5d6Y3PRhAwXpwY%20KYRCyBgAjrKU53jgnOsSpK1CuQdvbB99GwNDfaYArmM1KPEbIAAIorJZJpU-bW%20PpwQTHzR6j8xgC-OyBkTIRxehXvMArAa9X-FFL2iGMjGYj9x8Y2Wa%20XJGkRkasIRkfehZGGLHgpI-kfgBAxWL0UdI2QFKNjNWisZyo2hSxR9E6jugBo0KjVjNHRes%20u-TmX6Oj6LwM8Ho10D6M%20kbt2EciwwGiNjH4ja5ktIiZ7w0WWT2x%20MIsecZxZURD5G0r7CBksCkx45exjsZnh7HHTGh4sAOCONt6TjM4M40hDI2XG0A1xyw9Jb1guh3jqceMDfDeNPGNpb8b45TEaL1D-jOK6vCgPjAgmwTDACE-DGhPTK4ToAEyEZdJgFmNwwp9EyZdTWCYOTNV5XAWqcsEmaiRJ6KGcVJPVVyT4Uq4qUAUXoyzCtJ-k29gMw1F2mjV1kyKecbtXOTPZ1Gb1an0DX6TOGqpW%20aPVsmyr84D06zKlM20ZTrMoMKYoX421FxSpq8CqZtaNSNT87XyHuNak6mLEeptZQaa4xGn4czjU02mauZwhnQNpk8JAHtOgEPm6LF05QbdNPatL4pz0%20teih5ntrm0gM4qAsjNgQzYZ5sg7uNYngcoH1-pgmamieTbwKZs03vvTPMIszfRHM1-XBtHrXur5ym0nXMOrnJjAK2MBWYHMI82zSOusxSZFmNn6hzZ%20m9ecnYc3OzM5y-fULHO2hKzCPac6yImWjm%20zK5zENLZaaHXNp85hMIud07Ln6bNNla-6GfP6XGbV15m7uf3MC2GS%20hI20WFPORkLz%20Os27Wyd13m5Tb%203W5uZfNQ3abmF7CxgFhu-mdpAFt1shZBmoWneYF31kJc2OmXkyMFyAPBfgBYAkLp%20kOy-3KvvnPz35mi1FMpVl77BpFkqBEZ-g-n7GP8AespF4G3hr4rxutb2hnREg1kcADZFsmIOIaYNSTQHXOn85LoYAM4RAcDPXRsBIADye4y8l3T84e7RN0AJfFe5IgTxw21PWnGW1GxSbD5S%20Ixk%20A4bL4kPbM5BMvgD1rxiJQ8u2HgAEoBUGma8WIBLts0y7VQiu5xarvbVtUINu5nwTfi722aWUdgHRC8Tfbz7l96QNfa8t8hK77AOtY-frRHmLbm0t%209IHABs1ZAp9o1VBj-vcAAHg4IB3fZAcP3LET9iB3Kk1PQPuA4ANCCQF5E-2kHo8Uu33MAfAPXeWD4NFzpfsXwKHbNVMLoCYAHmyHLMZB6g9vsvHMH4sMB5amfvHmoHzD6QOchEBSAvgCDqotw6odoOaHoD7B%20A-5qMOU0CkAeszT%20uoQZHVMtXHI-LvoO%20HtDgR8o6Ee4O66xSLoOmlYtDCCH0ynh0Y5itnyKoaN%20cLXcRBDom7gqG9GBo8cd2F0Xd%204uacnujxp764zYOdu0Mbh%20wgcDe6PC3t9EYS0eqMMvdE6CPdUqjkR6-bEfcANUmhYThYl%20S4IddHBrJ5A5ycaO2aQT01KjDp1lOsC2Tph0wi130OGKO93NO0k6TVoUjmbBp%20bdC4F3R4NN1E3pSLsEmxndhAog%20V3Mi0odG7Eqq%20RUYGdxqQa4rQs5UAmQRA3ADqNwFCt052wu6RcCQAex98D41XHQG1xQBHOP4pz2LbCD0qIkfg31vviUYVDHOHs2xdsGGQGjcXsImyC52gGT7XP3ntzt8F88eR0VPlzimBpAGefWm3kCLKF386qUj49KSFuAHcXqX9z-CvaTSnpUQcsx3OpEOkSy3Mo9216YgEKpaUMpQXD9xLlQE426PtGF9ej9MAy6QAYufmmx0Z6RBGfin2iTsGi2-Hmk4zZzwSQCWK%20yYRHBXf4D2xEeOnbn9sU0j8CqLEC6SRJ6F9Cb9P5cYX07OF4VzdiymDjXNvas640dGI7jz7f50-gHbnEIm07WFjOwZbwuxSQ8y9Yi9AjCN2EhnCkX28XdyeOPFHrG5xh4-ruN2R0zdoVUg3bssTAnVyLgL3Ycub6B7Q97dK8neT7pQASb-idFCnvkwZ73Un3UawVjJOVtaTim3m9Hhr3W9Nl0Jy1EL5LXcDBD-e%20pTkgDkT7nD-R4G-ke8OYrSjtpxcxEc20CHH9yAF-d0e-2e3hj4N6Y8HfCPIHI73J7A8mAYBJ35Dqp--d7dOP77c7-p6OWHeiPN3hD4h6Q%20YNTvj3QbjByY9AgZOGHh7yp8QD3teBTbXb9MAY5vs7v%20Ht7sx5k8aeLuj3T76p5I%20IHruuH07z97O5-fzuLHzb3J1o4GoMAwP3by99u6g9dg737T2Q01FTTWOx4lypmzh%20PcOO0P17lx7o9Dey7w3w6eHNG9LfJ643FyBNxHdkhhOC3ETiwFE9cPRRYnShVFVW4bdBcYzHlst0vfJhLXMPQ7gD4%20%20gAD18nxGGOWomKeqJGDfh8p3g8tv1ugP4jsxLU9m6EH93ZDDT4%203Ud5oYP6n8FeWkrRdJendacxxZ9TtHrC7Ht3Wxy-9cTO%20Xuoo4XW9mdrO5aqzEMcs-OSrPxx-n2VqnG2e7P9nAkw56C5Odvhz%205z0yUC6bA3P4vhYc-k8gRZPPzI1p8-m8-bBgvCwELn5xBY2PjkyAgLq5%20Sji%20fP6cpX6F-89hfwvEQDz0iMi4jvLWtjyZDl1y7GhyqcXWL5xvi%20d1suKgHL0lwUxxYUvt6kAKl2S5pcp2aF9jDl0y4ViqXSAA%20c%20718Au3FGoo12m255c97qBXmk3yFVZFegSAZUYRHvUMlfXfn%20lnGV2d9jDHeFXGE2GwIRVdcA1XGr3fLTcVdvfHX3tz70a6KnZSMmZhc12qatdQYbXxU5QEheKvA-nXht8la6%202jeuxTR62V%20d4MtR2BMuP2MJqI2wG45INRp00ySIh2rAboY2MTCIjF9Eq9zm-a77sxFDDSKL3seMGiw%2062ifRYD22-BkubJLqJ1oeFh6tWUz4fi1DtbJoBpQnyjFiFl8OO3Bx5WfE6VSqSlICsU8rivswsr56Wq%20wUzty5n6MEvn3%20fpmGoppVqs4nVKygCF-baM9YQw7RPLkeWCUAK%203wqqA3-qGyYHwiezoucBj5kVxSPXG9UI3ncc%20gB%20f7nmpbH%20ca%20-0rXFcn0pm5dU-U-gNhcSkahEM-4xdb5n3hvnvxW7UqBLn3Z-jQLv4%20z3h73j8Zv1DhfZAUX6a8EMa37ODGw-dL7-B2E4sOvr34JaV9cEjfxmE33ny1%20TQPfuv732oiT9Xhh-6vo2GizN-KA2iXPxXMrht%20VE6r%20gYCVfFQtt%20vOrvtFu7-l%20RUB-%20vxsZZwD9osg-%20eLO6XsMmhHsrZW5MlZEir6B0lClsG6i-sZv%208q2LyCC9Ap6FyTpdkyUEyBpVfDUR-8pffQC%204wyVgCdQdRaAJqVrMOgHgDEAjUWZd79L2hmt2fXI0hMz-Ffxj8p-Yry01QAwnxICHfUJlcpplc5HI8xfNxw9EufUw3HJUAJoHgAHsKfWJAGIMgAYQNAbw0hQuAAgPysT5OgPhNklTvGECnYUQJcce-cLlPtYVPbT3NM8LQlVRUATyS1JQRCez7B8ATwhjMhZNRHUDt4JOjn8jMOfBWNSlK8E2gMA0gTuFtAtOGgIVAgMV7UjAzQLsC%207fgl0AkEXx1bsC8RAEFQ%20AgQLo0I7TwB9IFA8xgnJ4AeVQMCLEVwMvl3A5Nx49dApsCcCuCOIPORTAuPHMC5YQ008wbAtIQSDc3OMyVgTafQNv9BDdIK0CPAmsC8DwzFu2X1-A3gP0B%20AwGyAUJ7YCiVY4AGcD-8qqBuQnQSwHiC8VBDRgJBlYA7oNgC0Ak8AwCorXEC9YbjUuFWEpAeYJnh5-Z8CMxJghAMgC4ZPpX%20ssbPwJ4DAg1oI-AFZcUg-8ZA8QKapIIUoWBU0KKqm6Dbgwkj6CjYAYKGCXrZu2cYFFZQKEkJg9AK2DjWWYPwBlg8OGcw1guPA2Dpg1GQLBTlFj1wBGgw4Mp9nCBZWW94wOpHSDJPO5gxlRAKQIS8HzR6DGBtyU6CdkmtLkUlYMKHoMeDylZ4MGCQNAzzU92URsySC9A0kPypyQj-0pCowF4JpDBDawMgCUwX1UgC3gnxwN4NAb60IA9gnQJRC9giVEM87YBkOwh2HFEOZChJB4LZCClTkLUQeQkiHypwAjAMFCb9YVBFDrTMUL%20d%20EX9y50KWdBmVATkQGUdNYZSIL3N41dy0rd0WEyCgkYADalhANITwCUhMQGMiktooKuXG0a5CbVPhXg7ZVesVLVxg6NFLYIN04oJGEXbAvQgDl9CHIf0OwhAwjo2DCR9cVCGDaXEZD9ATgz4KECWAT4IatuvQnxLD9AFq2%20VaA8j2ODKw0mHOCirCQPsYDwaK3lk40P6WxFPALLFHZPJV3Bc5TFUAHm5e-VAGuM%20wu0gDRMqYHSQAkw95S6tMAOFw8MUFYcMs5x-UAnOIlEPiEnDSIacNMgsEbcIHDxxIcPm51wscKQxNw73n7CpwgpVfkDw68N3DbwwKm9Dyces1XDdOd32HBMEVAEPCbwk8Ms53fccKpRfwx8JSoZwucLfD5uaAk6U2VCcKPC9w0BQgiubOkQYAkIhcPcNYQFcLy0CfP4DbDOLeWWQRtfLqE7CljHsK-DZ-XMGcwsI3cVk0OIJcNhByIofyoinwjCKUx-w3TjPDGI%20eWYj2IvPmgi6IjPS4igteiLYjM6ckHm5PwxWxBF3w9v3xN4-BsNrCaQR3SRgrqFqSwA6AAEI8Q1hBFW7MlJLlFqDGYGJRwAmwyTTgAw2S6h59FIiqDRDnwgDmFkyEBsOLDTgxsJmVQAY%20Bqg6RHZzIBBid43PFIyAq3I9LIicK1IrwWhXnDaRa8EciY-BSKbC-of4E8jNkHyOMEjIgKIuCqSU1nwiK-Vn3bCKDB8HrVZHf6zjtELXbxIoMotqAIiyUPp36Rso-CIIhCIxNVyirYfKLG8L7QqIQsE7EqPW1qrKgR4hMqAYLLDO8HqOrCziEoCUhQBLoCGs1QniGZNyw3CKyFBgkAPy0pFe9QsFeeJhE9dMfZ-wpkalVkMwD1vKMNZcmtLr1-MVQ0mAG9AAgpQhBjozYX5CtQq6LsYYAvc3BDIA%206OW9KZVAN%20C7orrST8B8OTFwCkxMIWxDBLIGKoDdiIEnsYQYvfwM0Z4QhCsi7rMwhGCmA2v1Ul57VgPYC1IFGLrd3ZOEOaCggtWHvRIYqyIO8cI10EJimwyy3kDGVcxhs1JQ4vHWw1AjQPiCgxIoMZCUgumL%20xDAxmIyDKIrIMUwLA8VSsDbogIX0ZCg8rz7RHA9mNUDOY4wPmVRY3jSsNagnwNThsYg4Nxis-dFka9-uGAHZIqY5xhpiog1IIZiZYqoMSC1Ydhz0DDY6WJCieYrBGyCW7QWIgCtQ2wOZixY-pgliKocoLTouYk2JZjPAwkSViB9bgICC1YhEOCCQnGsAWZTo%204Pf9SYdkNnDqQqwkjNb9T4PlVGAJ6M%20iN9OIgBCgQ49EntFg%20VTlCrDEENCh1gjONuNhURsChCYzcOP2Dg4huzxjggwsLODXI8VlQBrg5kOjj--OOPVCvtJONziU48YPTipgv4OTjs46L1FI1fUEKwRnorUOViqTKuPFDa4poPrj1Y%209HORU4e0NRCuY9EL1QRPMYEhi1yMGzxDveCpkJDD4j43FjSgpUPoBTop4I5CE41T1dM7mQuPlDkglAGvjdou%20PjiwwzULU0hYskURi1YQ0OjBF4iUINiTQ5wh3j%20aF%20LAS9zD%20Nvju4h%20LMJf47UP-i9QkbQNDRQxeOlC6QmVD1iubK0McAbQ%20YM3jHQqfTH1ooN0MFQcoOcJTCdIOSwzDWXLMOEgZ4U0DDDAEgMIOjejM8lYSneeMPedaEv0IYSuEtS08UuQ1hNzClvQGKiim43E0CYHo%20SOcjqw8tREA4Y%20sOciiYxRjGtD9PCPKjGo3EC7DKuWTS-CjA%20CI%20UZI8Pm7DgrC8NMS-wzOnAibicKNZEn5ESOoiM%20TiMvCQIwcPsT9wn8IfDvEjXwsT4%20BcXqjrEr8MIQvE48J8TgI-xKiSJ0UKMcTXwrm3EimpSSJiSdwgJMX8gkuGWgigI%208IyS4ko2AcTvQyCKaloI0VTgi7E%20JNzB3kNCIiicQOpOcTFwjPTcS8%20a6MpldEtkDqjKo-RMMSrE3sIoj5-VpMsTRwgSI8MhIzJh4ifE1iOGTgk4YTJQBkpiLV9ZkrolKDUAMZIYipI6dVcTzE2vkkik-FJPWkFEw-VkSrI1QxUibrdSM0j84nSPHjcwAyI-AUokyJWD9AcyIr8uAJsOCiTA2yKcSixSKOcinIz4Ksj3I-CASjvIxhF8ja%20Z4CjJYTQKLjQsQGyLCj7I-5KLDoojRNiiqoeKNwAvIpKLSEuAJ5IBAXHJuDKjTaYNBqi9EzsOmokHNqPjskfE5hJSKooiKyiD0HKNCTiI6qKpSuHGlOKjA7dpjCEeovqJ4gywkmKmjlE75VBYxo4SEmieo4mNmjXQHqNeiWxaKVFFXQUE1IAGAF-wExyqGXERIfSau1SlaYj2PpirYgoJdj5Y-0Dfiyg41NiDGYnoWH87YjlQdj8gkWLNT%20Kd2JiD%20rW1LUE5YoCkVicg3wKDjl4loIRD7-ZaLmECLNaIYANo1VK2jjk5Mm1TvebWP1SZ4TeMtibU4wJdTbRaoItSLYyWOcCKgr1KwBMg22L5j-Up1N5DTUrNNNikmd1M9iJ6QtJ9jXY%205P9j-UhoNViV40OM2NQ0wrVvxlhSCEWA6VYJHwhdyVkWORukqJ2HMqxTUwUB24OpHCkx05BAnSRbKdJtpVOcKEZg5Q2gAAABdrS5tjkHiGM4agK8C3SbIFgEdUEAGEBWoB00aMuFmJbFNdBJAVMknsYAEgGkAhhUaPGjSAEdKMh90w9JpEZbaTG3Td020Bzlj009IHA9GS9P7SNABNllZAqPRiVxtIIYSQQPIY0hAzObS1zSsETMAB3SInI0DAy2HCDIvT-A9QJgyA1eDLpBkM63FeMt1abFnpWxFVKXo4pEjMWBo00AD7TSMt9Sdhh0%20dMcBx0jTEnTu6QjyClZ079PtU%20MxdIEzl0oTM0810nEOi8gMvDN4yD0iYDIACMj8QHAvQYjKvSYMm9PhE70zpDwN-rJqBfS304TI-ThIMTLgBf01TPrM%20iRTI24EM0DNAAT0wjKLBtM6DNgyFaYgCcykM4TJQyaM9DOfE7WHcQxkHMocHwyXM8DPcyoMzjPIyfMyjP8zqM40hBVECUTl9xs7CTlGRWSKuM5x8qHLJOVIAPLILVO8ArP%20tis6gJKhYYz5OIBgaW8CsVrY5ZTIBm2PVDKy2QPLM0SW1exjayisv0HJjmQanSRD%20ZOdKUQGsy%20UtUGM6lSYyQ8SuMKyDAEmESlss0oFyzbQLgB6yKssGPIC-gdbNtBhopRDhjas6MHqzBFRrJNlAwFrP5odslyLEDmwzERFSrss5I3BBsrUnWpdAS8LGz5lPLRD8b47x0HSnYJrLoT0sE7IQ1gw-JRfFgFTU2p0REv33%20VyzN7OhzBDdzRGUi4F8TUcpCUWjhdcvOpARyrwJHLSVxIVHLyxvsgiwUBvHNjKshfsuwjfgAcnHL7VdGCOVBzM0FHLUFbHYTKhz3FcQkusTPdHMBy1EPHNJUIlPFIkJuc5ggxyWvXnOAJgc5HIJyWczim7Sy9bxhEZeOLfk2zC1SmRCYTic6Pjwt6RYnm8CmIk0pY7ybyzUQYOOJg4odcubwSYcwYLUTdKXK3Ln0kU8bQ9wi4C3L1y5mDLIf8YpMUTilJGLoEWyCyJXI1y8TEVKDzayLXK9BXc0PLCZDNNyh6ZjcixFNy76D1EjyZyPlUdBXBFPIKYTIDjEcSv-XOWzc7c1PLFlvwVIn3JSAaQGVA5ZImBdBy8vZy5sS9VInkkfSDoQvMUQ0CCJg8QL5IOtOKADngCkAKCVukieQfLiDu8y5lJIeYLDOZBllOGL6Vb5KrG5je8m0OtidAEdUmhmyaAGYRbkzig3ykALkDOyZ8qMDnzGslSCXzvklfNXVhPMvgIZcmcyg4EdLQ8D3DcQBUiDBuac-Kj5Joy5h3ycWO-KPBH85-Jpp7QCMXfyB1dMRKBekWfOZE3Bbq0mgVINbOSYK4KwKAK18gdR3ztRcAsPzICnoW7Je8uApIAECwAtXzL8wUUuZpAFnmCgACxfKjAAbBDTSQ8ClSFUo3SIkiEVPVKwLIASAD-Ovzms02WYKeNVgvYKB1TZD%20iUKFkHGF7QNgo4LyGQQuYQhCiqhEKoCsQv4LwtGFx%20o0BBdHLA5CnoQ61FC3PkkKyASUkzMIhNQo9JRCrQokLQuQQoYhjC%20QtMKBCvQukLLCjQoMEFCswu018wHIVdBPkoMAJSbsuOLDD3NTQvEKUsTfM9UH2L-LcLaBDwtciQKfFMQzjI1yN8KuQ3HOByAi7QrMId8rfMuYa819Mup78rgBLAy87IsryXQCrBPyqC1ACgksi6QGRSbCpQugkfoPfLnyrqDAtp0elSgtaBVUGop0L7Eb7KbysADoT%20y-wOLFHZnVW1yIDMmPwiboiQPIt6KW8lECiDQIEFNQBxXFMTHDLzYYvglFqeeQmKOhaYuIA%20i9OFbz5irsEWLb1SbPL0LBBiS54OhJRXsZ8i0zO4AiioO1kh7i0KwCpG8vYtmK28rsF7RO8kfLEj5uNooHyTENFmHzGY0fLz5x835wfJp8z5IgL58kor7zQSbmLfzkCqHGCKeNNFh3yGi0Y1hLmi4-MRKPoZEqQKiCubks4b8y0h-yH8p8KfylwAApRKSSmHN04wiopkpK-82kp7Z6SlwstwSRMAqaKPxTAqcLsC2AvYz4ClSEQLCCrkvnBUCnkqh44S0QqFLD4WgvwLOSgdXdluAMgscAKC0otaBHRJUvoL5uRgsgU5CwIj4LJSiryygXqKwpNLnC1UryMZCqwpSKzSpr30L7SxwqLSbS2ouULDC2AHUKTCwIs9K7Skm29K6KN0tNLbSiwrHhQyj0q6KISF0ocK-S1IuIK8%20YgBoFPAOGK8LYiqyISK%20c5IqcLOitIvRLThFWzCLUyyIpuzoit0EzKmw7Mslz%201awv9KLEdIpCL5uSopyLf80ADuLa8x4oRKbQiopeLkI6MqvyvOKCXqKzsvkqPy1ENotBILEfMqTLyGFpTmEZimrSpyOldYv-MxiswnmhJi8cRLAlyokEOK9zBYoXgaoWW2CQ4sW23zA1y0Yv09W-bYvykOyvcrIg5iw8uOLjy-CDzDvsoewGLrrNUAjFaxUMxSFJhROONMpnI7g3tzIfMBQdt3D6xcImnYJCmRAIHKARAFBRvgoiEK3qFH8KnMaHyFBURWzfJMK4zzfhiACOHCCSfHDSBhI3Pq3481UePOdCRKdcqoqWFPRhbh9AY4z48mK2XFNZZMbM2WKikCCqQQT%20LwFwqbQSMFbh24d0IIqSFZ6FhAiE64mNIxfdzSKcxMeEJjKPcqRWpylIE8BBQXQC8qvMeeFalVRVTd41yCRg1gBEBHTVwxgAWQUwyJAgaeDUtchgrCD%20YEFGiG8FTTIrmp8FAGVXvRqmdSv69NK1gG0qAuO230rIIQyptZjK563DD3gtWXMrTDKypsqkAOysirHK5kGcrBwVyrf13K-QE8qGS%20WHvRP0%20WEyyvcvGDmK8iSHN0BfldkiXAMkKot1NLzfRK51iFSCRFphMRDCuoyqpEDqr7rBqplDJ8rEXhsgzV6h3Auqy6hqqWEbqos56M5VKmzuoZi19Bvy2ME8AwyQAOGKVq0IIQCFNTMh%20iH9DWImyZqorTkxE9RaugNQ1fuTWqMSfMBIg0wjbxIAB8bML2rhcy72WRo9eGMFFqmFNXGx%20dATCRArYKPhOr2zeCUGpdYnqlMknxcivUxE4PogtFnQiYHq1YkzgN5M5AEgFKFWpPYPuM2436k90QnDoVRrsavfVgqsKiNGgBhMIkGiJVIttF%20rcQKPmVAEQEsBOKRzYmpbByayMkpqHwGmrpqGap6oVQUmeAA4hW0LBGQqmARvkASYa6iumAoNUgDA0FFfoFit6gjcAT0NAREnWqYATauLcSCC1U9RJfGpSpqOaksCJgziD8F1rJoWmpLAsIc8rKrekbcBrzS0hDUdSEMpBFkxD8zCLtrSlVSjiwgqq2p3Avq-9QFiHanZxQBnavKqGCTKvuPA0IEGCtUpe82AIqho6h0LbjM6fmK6AQ6qKttBHawOo0zg6rkNyC465w2NMwI3AFnQsajIuvzgsdkkXA-qyaAdTyTe2rTqA6o2Extfa6DVUppgACsrr5MW2ojla6tgHrqg6yWpIBQ6kCo3BZcBAGEQQnDUHRAb2SOuyYKK0CCfB3kSqS2A0kaoxuFk67Op3FphM4qc5BUdCCECuwdCGzAw0-CwuKQ4MgDYyvylcrPLfylEH-LKhEgWAqIwhWD1E63ESsgrHHKUNPKnYdCr6hYQIWtQquCb%20skrcDHCt6QQGoBuw9AqEipBrQGJ0OorbLcUihq63MWqYqtYjYsyqPLCfVYqfLdivzxooTiuOU8q7FRVtX7firErYQd0MxBX6gSvErqhcEuk81CVrzhcIGKcgUrgcpSuQAVKoctC4AqDSq0qdwXSoBowasKt1MIq-gXQSNOMyosq2fPfFpkWA3UGSr%20BVKuEp04FysQamtbKp6c7VHipwVNpADj4aXQOgBCrFgZ4GEb7rURonFxGniTir57BKvntbKmMBSquQkyHSrEal21AANG3Ku0b0JXhTsE5hQ4vKrNPEWiqqOq6NGQA68nqpANcE61GaqIG1qrlUQm2qvCazCEHTQMcHGeg5FhMwasRsgq0aoSaJqpJsFF0sm-DmE5q9QIWrL6p2GWrzqqppuIrqrapUsdqkMNjDZI4mUXojqmDIqa-wGpuMwLq2prVq2jbAIerNa1wk2kDkV6qVNcQ8lWZAvqiutdBjap4tVsRigalyhoGuIgMhngVrTb1Z6zGI8tkG3Buwg4al-QRr0G50K1jkavGsXiMai5ogT3ZIurRqIEwmuM8baZQFJqqcCYtZquAeZtNquakZpQJmarco%20bQAL5s5q3ypYuIaeazZC%20B%20a-kGwQUKkzjDrWrWirgbiwfurI0ZagewFMpa3wIvpE9ZWsuq1auRseaLyTvGBb9amPMZhSW-EmhF-Gr2ptqV8puqxbgdHuqdrM6hloHqN6vPg9qdwWlpgBO6mussD-allsbrXav2o4TMACOoea0WXOtjqVIWALQAUqJOu8V16plvTqG6hiLZac62Vr3MEDAutxri65srJKy6tuupqq6vluNAU6lVt7rM61Fo5avOVuorqTWjuvpaRW6DUtahW9VpdbGW6KqFDzGEerHr7AieoOUYSD%20vm5tmwVHnrFgRev0Bl6nq1XqlWluzzDEjZ2EDMlMO%20BTaS9I%20ugRzkRACtgHNTU31ULIO52yZJAvdELbu-LlGaobTDUAgTiADwibBXnWmXSJ7LIoOrhG24iCZDLIqv0YpHfTttg9gLA8zRYD4H5xRck20pl%20IC2gJiICJ2h7C8hRkPFr6bXBedo2r1IsgLkjD9JdtVqV26GKlKJmH7zOqF2maM7wN2-MCU5XyUJKhLdObpr80NAadsyrb261BCdkEWFxVra0T5QCpRkHYLZBWcm2gQBHAL4CfAFBJv3eSpPQitixeWbBgFYG2QRs11J2%20RHvaioUFssa7CJxBqI8YgmNLbYOuulOR5AS6l4rfIDfLCRlswrKd96GUDuJqbJJtuA6u2tSp7Tw0i4pzb8QOADYzs2h8DzbNPeDvw8DSiGIw76ZZxk1YiQXEXkQa42tso6neETvbaeKG5r8gKOiTvfje2hzwVgqAkC3k7-3OZOv9a%20IdubaxYrr2UYymSiB47p-DjsHg52-duXa92l9s55hUuVPmFTOzdrFTDa8zvxaL4ofG0TkyY9rF5VDc9pv5TO69o46ZwDjs1ieAZEGPaz%20Rrw2kP2quO-aRc66z-bbiQDosj4UkDvBUsGBKlwYJizQBg6HsPeo%20Qy22xEQ7vW-UIoYcTBuMeqjO3A2w6gOz%20r-ACO2bP%20sSOqrp9QZOknDEFEu6juCMzi%20wR5KAaiMiwBBqO%20tUFfSVi2JyLBKwStg2MrYS4y-wHrr67AK%20%20vByCamjpztI-FYHCNxTYYx0tRjKiwNsk2hEjbd2wG8KKN2LV5r%20dtLXSy27cLDrro6w-FFHG6o-DazW6KLPS1hteLA%20yvR9ux8JCdeLY7ojtTuzbvedtu9rpLzbi7pKzpdjJP3OEkWroBoxswN8izoQek6Vhi1U8E0hij5EsBB6qQTEFwlkEJAGwkzRagHh6xAYClJBCe15IupvEKqGUid6l0DEBmobxDEA3LM0VcgZQIAA)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBsnc.png)

[Collection.find().forEach() definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpZPW.jpg)

Comment: well, you seem to be defining it yourself. As you are defining it, the callback of the `forEach` will receive a first argument of type T which, as you claim, has no `_id` field -- when in reality of course it does, since it's a document in a mongo collection. Your type definition for `Collection.find().forEach()` is wrong.

Comment: Can you please post the content of the images as text?

Comment: Not sure if Im doing it right but I 'forced' similar code to work my side doing something like this : `const Chats: Mongo.Collection<IChat> = new Mongo.Collection('chat');`

Answer (score 0):

In this case you're missing the `.fetch()` call after `.find()`.

It may be that mathamagically Meteor+Mongo can handle the syntax as you have it now but the easy way to make Typescript happy here is adjusting it to be the following:

```js
interface IChat {
    _id: string;
    name?: string
};

const Chats = new Mongo.Collection<IChat>('chat');

Chats.find().fetch().forEach(c => {
    console.log(c._id);
});
```

link to the solution in [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2118&ssc=1&pln=2108&pc=1#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)

[image]